# Field with this name is already defined error

Tags: atk4

I have a field 'slug' in my model and I set this field at $id_field property, but I got a error: 'Application Error: Field with this name is already defined'. I need to show this fild on the page, how can I do that?

**model source:**

```
<?php
class Model_Post extends Model_Table {
    public $table='posts';
    public $entity_code='posts';
    public $id_field='slug';

    public function prepareData($table, $columns = 'id,name')
    {
        $getData = $this->api->db->dsql()->table($table)
            ->field($columns)
            ->fetchAll();
        $return = array();
        $columns = explode(',', $columns);
        foreach ($getData as $data) 
        {
            $return[$data[$columns['0']]] = $data[$columns['1']];
        }

        return $return;
    }

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        //$this->hasOne('User', 'author');

        $category = $this->prepareData('categories', 'id,name');
        $user = $this->prepareData('users', 'id,realName');


        $this->addField('slug')->caption('Ссылка')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('author')->setValueList($user)->caption('Автор')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('category')->setValueList($category)->caption('Категория')->mandatory(true);
        //$this->addField('previewIMG')->setModel("filestore/Model_Image")->type("file")->caption('Изображение');
        $this->addField('title')->caption('Заголовок')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('date')->type('date')->defaultValue(date('Ymd'))->caption('Дата')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('body')->type('text')->caption('Текст поста')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('published')->type('boolean')->caption('Опубликовать');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please start using latest ATK4 version from Git master branch. It looks that you're also using some deprecated variables etc. It's better to always try to stick to latest version, because framework is in constant development all the time :)

Comment: @DarkSide I use atk v4.2.5 from github :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `prepareData` method in your code. Your model should look something like this:

```
<?php
class Model_Post extends Model_Table {
public $table='posts';
public $entity_code='posts';
public $id_field='slug';


function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('slug')->caption('Ссылка')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('author')->setValueList($user)->caption('Автор')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('category')->setValueList($category)->caption('Категория')->mandatory(true);
    //$this->addField('previewIMG')->setModel("filestore/Model_Image")->type("file")->caption('Изображение');
    $this->addField('title')->caption('Заголовок')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('date')->type('date')->defaultValue(date('Ymd'))->caption('Дата')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('body')->type('text')->caption('Текст поста')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('published')->type('boolean')->caption('Опубликовать');
}
}
```

There are several ways to display all these fields on the page. If you want to input values from user

### `Way # 1` : Form

```
$f = $this->add('Form');
$f->setModel('Post');
$f->addSubmit();
```

### `Way # 2` : Grid

```
$this->add('Grid')->setModel('Post');
```